# Overlapping range inputs. On click change input with closest value

Tags: javascript, input

I have two overlapping range inputs, this creates a multi range input effect.

I want it so that whenever a click is made on either of these, the input with the closest value to the newly clicked value, is changed. Not entirely sure how to go about this.

How could I do this?

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var supportsMultiple = self.HTMLInputElement && "valueLow" in HTMLInputElement.prototype;

  var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");

  self.multirange = function(input) {
    if (supportsMultiple || input.classList.contains("multirange")) {
      return;
    }

    var values = input.getAttribute("value").split(",");
    var max = +input.max || 100;
    var ghost = input.cloneNode();

    input.classList.add("multirange", "original");
    ghost.classList.add("multirange", "ghost");

    input.value = values[0] || max / 2;
    ghost.value = values[1] || max / 2;

    input.parentNode.insertBefore(ghost, input.nextSibling);

    Object.defineProperty(input, "originalValue", descriptor.get ? descriptor : {
      // Dang you Safari >:(
      get: function() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function(v) {
        this.value = v;
      }
    });

    Object.defineProperties(input, {
      valueLow: {
        get: function() {
          return Math.min(this.originalValue, ghost.value);
        },
        set: function(v) {
          this.originalValue = v;
        },
        enumerable: true
      },
      valueHigh: {
        get: function() {
          return Math.max(this.originalValue, ghost.value);
        },
        set: function(v) {
          ghost.value = v;
        },
        enumerable: true
      }
    });

    if (descriptor.get) {
      // Again, fuck you Safari
      Object.defineProperty(input, "value", {
        get: function() {
          return this.valueLow + "," + this.valueHigh;
        },
        set: function(v) {
          var values = v.split(",");
          this.valueLow = values[0];
          this.valueHigh = values[1];
        },
        enumerable: true
      });
    }

    function update() {
      ghost.style.setProperty("--low", input.valueLow * 100 / max + 1 + "%");
      ghost.style.setProperty("--high", input.valueHigh * 100 / max - 1 + "%");
    }

    input.addEventListener("input", update);
    ghost.addEventListener("input", update);

    update();
  }

  multirange.init = function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=range][multiple]:not(.multirange)")).forEach(multirange);
  }

  if (document.readyState == "loading") {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", multirange.init);
  } else {
    multirange.init();
  }

})();
```

```css
@supports (--css: variables) {
  input[type="range"].multirange {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original {
    position: absolute;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original::-moz-range-thumb {
    transform: scale(1);
    /* FF doesn't apply position it seems */
    G z-index: 1;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange::-moz-range-track {
    border-color: transparent;
    /* needed to switch FF to "styleable" control */
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost {
    position: relative;
    background: var(--track-background);
    --track-background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent var(--low), var(--range-color) 0, var(--range-color) var(--high), transparent 0) no-repeat 0 45% / 100% 40%;
    --range-color: hsl(190, 80%, 40%);
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: var(--track-background);
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-moz-range-track {
    background: var(--track-background);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" multiple value="10,80" />
```

Comment: Maybe I could draw your attention to this: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/. Look at the example on top. I have submitted a couple of pull requests (in a branch that will at some point go stable) that enable the exact same functionality for more handles (clicking on the slider moves the handle closer to the click - even if two or three handles overlap (same position), the handle that can move will move). I am not sure whether you will consider using another library. The license is WTFPL.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use native input[type=range].

Comment: OK. Another question. In your example the left handle cannot be dragged right now, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug in some browsers. I'm hoping this will fix it.

Comment: `Dang you safari` is okay. The other safari reference in the comments is unnecessarily uncouth. Careful not to get caught out with poor comments in production code!

Comment: I've made a css-only double range input: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/mdEJMLv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to capture a mouse event on the element and calculate how close it is to the high marker vs. the low marker and decide which one to update based on that.  Also, because these are two stacked input elements, you'll probably have to pass the event to the low range input manually.

[Here's my go](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadDeveloper/khk0hLfx/) at creating such a function:

```
function passClick(evt) {
  // Are the ghost and input elements inverted? (ghost is lower range)
  var isInverted = input.valueLow == ghost.value;
  // Find the horizontal position that was clicked (as a percentage of the element's width) 
  var clickPoint = evt.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
  // Map the percentage to a value in the range (note, assumes a min value of 0)
  var clickValue = max * clickPoint;

  // Get the distance to both high and low values in the range
  var highDiff = Math.abs(input.valueHigh - clickValue);
  var lowDiff = Math.abs(input.valueLow - clickValue);

  if (lowDiff < highDiff && !isInverted || (isInverted && lowDiff > highDiff)) {
    // The low value is closer to the click point than the high value
    // We should update the low value input
    var passEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {screenX: evt.screenX, clientX: evt.clientX});
    // Pass a new event to the low "input" element (which is obscured by the
    // higher "ghost" element, and doesn't get mouse events outside the drag handle
    input.dispatchEvent(passEvent);
    // The higher "ghost" element should not respond to this event
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    console.log("move ghost");
    // The high value is closer to the click point than the low value
    // The default behavior is appropriate, so do nuthin
  }
}

ghost.addEventListener("mousedown", passClick);
```

I put this code immediately above the `input.addEventListener("input", update);` line in your sample, and it seems to work. See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadDeveloper/khk0hLfx/).

**Some provisos though:**

- I only tested in Chrome. IE might have some trouble based on how I replicated the event.  It *may* use a mechanism other than `dispatchEvent`... like `fireEvent` or something.
- Initially I coded it assuming that the "ghost" element always kept track of the high range. I've since updated things to invert the event dispatching when the ghost element has the lower value--but I sped through it.

Comment: I'm in the middle of using two input ranges and I've managed to get it working on all but firefox (v55.0.3). I tried your solution with no luck but I think you're onto something which could work if we tweak it a bit

Answer (score 2):

Here's something simple you could use. Although you might want to customize the style.
I am altering the `z-index` of the slider element based upon its proximity to the cursor.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddg8oy9n/2/)

HTML

```
<input id='a' type='range' />
<input id='b' type='range' />
<label role='info'></label>
```

JS

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

a.onmousemove = function(e) {
    MouseMove.call(a, e);
};
b.onmousemove = function(e) {
    MouseMove.call(b, e);
};

var MouseMove = function(eventArg) 
{

    var max = parseInt(a.max),
        min = parseInt(a.min),
        diff = max - min,
        clickPoint = eventArg.offsetX / a.offsetWidth,
        clickPointVal = parseInt(diff * clickPoint) + min;

    /* absolute distance from respective slider values */
    var da = Math.abs(a.value - clickPointVal),
        db = Math.abs(b.value - clickPointVal);

    // Making the two sliders appear above one another only when no mouse button is pressed, this condition may be removed at will
    if (!eventArg.buttons) 
    {
        if (da < db) 
        {
            a.style.zIndex = 2;
            b.style.zIndex = 1;
        } 
        else if (db < da)
        {
            b.style.zIndex = 2;
            a.style.zIndex = 1;
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('label').innerHTML = 'Red: ' + a.value + ', Green: ' + b.value + ', X: ' + eventArg.clientX;
}
```

CSS

```
input {
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#a {
    z-index: 2;
}

#b {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea and I've implemented it myself to deal with the firefox incompatibility for multiple input ranges but suggest some changes to how you deal with identifying the closest handle, much like @theMadDeveloper has done, you should switch to using percentages. I'm not sure why you're using `* 100 / 160`

Comment: I tried to edit your solution but there is too much to change so take a look at this example below if you want to see something thats cross browser compatible 
[Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/doz87/pen/pWbywG)

Comment: FYI - My example includes an restriction that the min and max can't be more than 10% apart

Comment: @doz87 Thanks for the link. I did not remember my approach from when I had wrote this answer so I had to go through this again. The value 160 is the default width of the control. I should have either specified that in the CSS or mentioned what it is.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense then